# Is it possible to prepare cat states of light over different frequencies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, superposition, schroedingers-cat

Is it possible to form a superposition state of a single photon in multiple frequencies? As an archetypal example, consider the Schrödinger's-cat state
$$
|\psi\rangle = |1;\omega\rangle + |1;2\omega\rangle,
$$
with some arbitrary mode and polarization chosen for each of the two frequencies, and where $|1;\omega\rangle$ is the single-photon Fock state for frequency $\omega$.

Now, a state like $|\psi\rangle $ is not an eigenstate of the free-field hamiltonian, but that's not a huge in-principle objection, since all it means is that the state will evolve in time as the two states beat against each other. However, I'm not sure how you'd actually make such a state: the closest I can think of is to halt an SPDC process halfway through, but that would prepare a different state,
$$
|\psi_2\rangle = |2;\omega\rangle + |1;2\omega\rangle,
$$
which has the conspicuous feature that it *is* an eigenstate of the free-field hamiltonian.

So: is it possible, in practice, to prepare single photons with that kind of frequency content? What is required, in terms of breaking of temporal translation symmetry by the apparaturs, or otherwise?

Comment: Relevant: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.223601, https://physics.aps.org/articles/pdf/10.1103/Physics.9.135

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but, e.g., if you prepare a hydrogen atom in an $n=3$ state, then it has multiple decay branches available. Doesn't this produce a superposition of different photon energies?

Comment: @BenCrowell Then there are two options, neither of which fits the bill. One way is to decay, say, from 4p to 3s and 3d, but that leaves the photon entangled with the atom, with no single-partite coherence. The other way is to |decay from 3p to 1s⟩ + |decay from 3p to 2s and from there to 1s⟩, in which case the atom gets factored out but you now have a superposition of the form |one photon⟩ + |two photons⟩.

Comment: On the other hand, I guess you could excite the atom into |2p⟩+|3p⟩ and then have it decay into |1s⟩, hopefully transferring the coherence of the initial superposition (which breaks time-translation invariance) into the cat state of light, so that probably does it, but I was hoping for something a bit closer to implementable ─ i.e. something using nonlinearities in bulk media in a coherent way, driven by externally-imposed states of light.